# Tag change request: Minecraft-Bukkit

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Can we change [bukkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bukkit) to [minecraft-bukkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bukkit)? People that are new to Minecraft may think that Bukkit is a totally different game, and therefore may tag their questions something else, without even reading the description.

Comment: I agree. This also fits the precedent of [tag:minecraft-tekkit].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No argument here. I've performed the merge and made [bukkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bukkit) become a synonym of [minecraft-bukkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bukkit).